# Background images on Angular apps built with Yeoman

Tags: css, angularjs, background-image

I've started to create a website that will host all of my various projects. I've used Yeoman to scaffold an Angular app with Bootstrap. So far, in my index.html, I have the following snippet:

```
<body>
<!--[if lt IE 10]>
  <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
<![endif]-->
<div>
    <acme-navbar creation-date="main.creationDate"></acme-navbar>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>

<!-- build:js(src) scripts/vendor.js -->
```

Each project will be associated to a menu item, and will be displayed in the ng-view div. A sample of code can be seen below:

```
    <div class="row">
    <h1 class="text-center">Company list</h1>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Company Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="companyInfo in vm.responseData">
            <td class="{{companyInfo.company.red_yellow_green}}">{{companyInfo.company.company_name}}</td>
            <td>{{companyInfo.company.address}}</td>
            <td>{{companyInfo.company.city}}</td>
            <td>{{companyInfo.company.state}}</td>
            <td>{{companyInfo.company.country}}</td>
            <td>{{companyInfo.company.status}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I want to be able to have a custom background image for each project. My question is, how can I do this since the body tag is in the index.html? If I were to create a plain html web page (without scaffolding or angular), I could use the css property background-image: url(); and use the background size of cover. But I don't know how this is possible with my current setup.

Comment: A simple solution would be to set the currently selected project name on `$rootScope` and change the body tag to `<body ng-class="{{projectName}}">`.

Comment: @Phil - This is what I was looking for. Thanks! If you are willing to post that as an answer, I would be happy to mark it correct.